# Delete files uploaded using the wp_upload_bits() function

Tags: uploads

I made an image uploader in WordPress using the

```
wp_upload_bits()
```

function. Here is my code how I do it

```
 $upload = wp_upload_bits($_FILES['portfolio_img']['name'][$i], null, file_get_contents($_FILES['portfolio_img']['tmp_name'][$i]));
   if(isset($upload['error']) != false ) {
   $portfolio_imgs[] = $upload['url'];
   add_post_meta($id, 'portfolio_imgs', $portfolio_imgs);
   update_post_meta($id, 'portfolio_imgs', $portfolio_imgs);
 }
```

I would like to allow the administrator to delete the uploaded images in the back end. I made the option and it deletes the meta infos, I can also get the images absolute url, for example:

```
http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/road.jpg
```

However I can't use the the

```
unlink()
```

PHP function for absolute URLs. I tried to convert the URLs to relative path but I can't make it work even with if I get a relative path like:

```
/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/road.jpg
```

or

```
wp-content/uploads/2016/08/road.jpg
```

I always get this error:

Warning: unlink(/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/road.jpg) [function.unlink]: No such file or directory in /home/...

I am really stuck with this any help is appriciated!

Comment: How do you get URL?

Comment: I have an array of each URL and I have a for loop to read each value 1 by 1 and do something with it 'for ($d=$delete_length-1; $d > -1; $d--) { if($selected[$d] == "delete") { unlink($current_images[$d]);} }'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your code snippet `$upload['file']` will contain the full file path to the file.  You could save this in the meta so that it's retrievable whenever you want to delete the file.

Comment: I have the absolute path of the file but I don't know how to delete it

Comment: Ah - that's not what your question says.  The absolute path will be from your server's filesystem root, not your website's root.

Comment: Oh - do you have any idea how could I convert this URL:
[link](http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/road.jpg)
to something I can use in unlink() function to delete the file?

Comment: Don't try and convert from the URL, just save `$upload['file']` for later.

Comment: $upload['file'] has the absolute path of the file
`wp_die($upload['file']);`
returns:
`D:\work2016\xampp\htdocs\wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/road.jpg`
How do I delete the file using this absolute path?

Comment: Hmm - I would have expected it to have the right separators for your system.  I'm not a Windows man.

Comment: I uploaded it to test so we see the live URL

'unlink("/home/arfgocom/public_html/mysite.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/road.jpg");'

Comment: Ah - that shifts the goalposts back again then.  So that unlink should work.  If it doesn't, are you getting any PHP error?

Comment: I added a 'wp_die();' so I see it says: 
No such file or directory